# After Effects P/B-frames aka motion vectors for Datamosh replication

Tags: after-effects

I am trying to replicate [Datamoshing](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/datamoshing) with After Effects. I'm close but I need to link the displacement map to motion vectors rather than just colors and brightness values. I know AE recognizes motion vectors as it uses them for motion blur. If there is a way to extract and move P/B-frames and apply them to other I frames that would be perfect but I haven't found that yet.

I figure if i could translate motion vectors into shades of black and white i could apply the displacement map to that layer using luminosity. Is there any way to do that? Perhaps extracting motion blur as a separate layer with an alpha channel?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this kind of effect is to use [Glitch](https://aescripts.com/data-glitch/) - a plugin from aescripts.  It's not going to let you properly combine two sources, but it will go a long way towards giving you "broken" looking digital video...